# Polynomials who share roots with their derivatives

Tags: polynomials

What is the characteristic distinguishing polynomials who’s roots are shared between all of it’s derivitives?(execpt for constant polynomials)
like $x^2+2x+1$.
All quadratics of this type obey $b^2-4ac=0$
Thus, all cubics:$ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ must obey $4b^2-12ac=0$ or more simply $b^2-3ac=0$
And the cubic solution.
Can I get help on studying those polynomials? Maybe a solution for an arbitrary power?
note: for an nth degree polynomial there are n variables and n-1 equations.

Comment: They are just in the form $(x-a)^n$

Comment: Sharing a root with its first derivative means the polynomial has a repeated root. Sharing a root with all its non constant derivatives means that there is only a single repeated root (the multiplicity is equal to the degree of the original polynomial).